# C++11 Pointer Uniquify Helper Function

Tags: c++, c++11, type-safety, unique-ptr

In C++11, I'm missing a syntatic sugar for uniquifying a pointer into `std::unique_ptr`. I therefore wrote the following litte helper function `std::uniquify_ptr` typically used to easy (non-constructor) *assignment* of mutable class members (typically different kinds of *caches*).

```cpp
#include <memory>

namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    inline unique_ptr<T> uniquify_ptr(T* ptr)
    {
        return unique_ptr<T>(ptr);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something from a *safety* point of view here? Is some similar function already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique_ptr<T>` can already directly construct from a `T*`, so there's little need. Such a factory function has little use except for syntactic sugar, e.g., `auto x = make_unique<T>(...);`. Also, your `move` is redundant.

Comment: The whole idea of my factory function `std::uniquify_ptr(ptr)` is that the compiler can deduce the template parameter from `ptr`. Why can't a `std::unique_ptr<T>` guess `T` for me aswell? I've tested these things on GCC-4.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no similar function already available. How is

```cpp
auto ptr(std::uniquify_ptr(new T()));
```

any better than

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(new T());
```

? I.e., why *should* this exist? It's not saving you much if anything.

Comment: I removed the `std::move` from my snippet. I still think it's more convenient since `T` can be deduced from the argument in my wrapper. For example it suffices to write `std::uniquify_ptr(ptr)` instead of `std::unique_ptr<SomeType>(ptr)`.

Comment: if the name `T` is more than 6 characters long, the `uniquify_ptr` way starts to pay off :)

Comment: Is `make_`... some kind of C++/Boost standard way of naming factory functions?

Comment: @Nordlöw : The standard only has `make_shared` and `make_pair`, but yes, I do believe those set the precedent for the naming convention, as Boost widely follows it.

Answer (score 0):

@Schaub: I'm using this to *change* the value of an existing *mutable* `std::unique_ptr` class member. In that case

```
m_hashA = std::uniquify(new Hashes(cnt));
```

is more convenient than

```
m_hashA = std::unique_ptr<Hashes>(new Hashes(cnt)));
```

vere the member is declared as

```
mutable std::unique_ptr<Hashes> m_hashA; ///< Hash Table for Alternatives.
```

Thanks